# Site Icon Disappearing in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, bug

I choose custom logo for my site but it's change in main page only 
Others pages show the default sharepoint site icon. But Sharepoint Designer shows the icon correct!!! 
I test my site with IE 9, IE8 - icon disappear but when I test site with Chrome the icon is correct.
Is anybody meets same problem?
Please, help me : What i must looking for ?

Comment: I saw this happening in the central admin too, lately. the site icon is showed on the landing page, but not on subpages. Don't know if this happened before SP1/CU June, too. Only checked this with IE8, though.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your custom logo either located in the document library configured with certain permissions which result in your logo displayed correctly by SharePoint Designer OR your logo size is too big which result in IE failed to render it properly - the recommended size: 60 x 60 pixels

To fix the first possible issue, I'd recommend to go with the basic. Copy the logo file to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES and change the logo URL to: http://localhost/_layouts/images/seMallSolutionLogo64x64.gif

Cheers